# I can't get 2 objects to show on the screen in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to get 2 objects to show on the screen using JFrame and I am trying to move them around. I got 1 object to appear on the screen and then I tried to get 2 of them on there, but I just can't get it to work

This is my Main

```
package animate;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Square s = new Square(50, 100, 2);
        //Square s2 = new Square(300, 50, 1);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setSize(700, 350);

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(new Square(50, 100, 2));
        panel.add(new Square(300, 50, 1));

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("hi");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is my square class(It's supposed to draw a square but I am using a circle for testing purposes for right now)

```
package animate;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Square extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    double x, y, vel;

    public Square(int x, int y, int vel){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vel = vel;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Ellipse2D circ = new Ellipse2D.Double(this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
        g2.fill(circ);
        t.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x += 0;
        y += 0;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredDimension(){
        return new Dimension(100, 540);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override getPreferredDimension() and return an appropriate dimension. Also avoid hard-coding the size of your frame, and use pack() instead so that it has the appropriate dimension. And read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html to learn how to properly start a swing application.

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate more on the getPrefferedDimension() method? Do I use it on the panel or the frame? Also do I use pack() on the frame or the panel? I don't think I understand really, because I still can't get it to work really

Comment: The Square class must override getPreferredDimension. pack() must be called on the frame before making it visible.

Comment: Sorry I just feel like I'm too dumb for this. I am getting a "Method does not override method from its superclass" error on the @Override before the getPreferredDimension() method. I don't know what am I doing wrong...

Comment: I don't know either since I can't see your code.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the updated code..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's getPreferredSize(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize--

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much!